# Где имеет смысл использовать Optional?

Tags: java-8, optional

[В следующей статье про Optional](https://fernandocejas.com/2016/02/20/how-to-use-optional-on-android-and-java/) такое резюме:

> не загрязняйте свой код использованием везде Optional, используйте
>   их осторожно, где это имеет смысл (don't pollute your code with
>   Optional everywhere, use them carefully where it makes sense).

А где имеет смысл использовать `Optional`? Есть ли чёткое разделение (или хотя бы какие-нибудь рекомендации), когда лучше использовать `if-else`, а когда `Optional`?

Comment: оборачивать в optional нужно поля класса. Для того, чтобы не делать самостоятельно проверок типа !=null . C использованием лямбд выражений условия на проверку null условий существенно сокращается:)

Comment: @БорисовМакс вместо `!=null` будет `isPresent`.

Comment: @Suvitruf не правильно выразился. я имел в виду что внутренняя конструкция после проверки на null существенно укорачивается с применением лямбд:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прежде всего, все разговоры об Optional - это холивар. Однако есть ряд следствий:

1. Правильное использование Optional упрощает контракт в приложении, когда разработчик библиотеки явно показывает, какие поля могут быть null. А разработчик конечного приложения явно видит, где необходимо сделать проверки, а где можно обойтись без них. Тут важны ключевые слова *правильное использование* и *явно видит*. В реальности сама переменная типа Optional<*> может быть null'ом.
2. Работа с Optional ударяет по производительности, так как может потребовать выделение в куче дополнительных объектов - самих классов Optional, лябд. Заодно увеличивается вероятность боксинга примитивных значений.
3. При работе с Optional'ами увеличивается объем кода.

Из всего этого есть важные следствия:

- Вопросы об Optional ближе к вопросам о Code Review, о Style Guide. При правильном подходе код будет более чистый, при неправильном - всё станет только хуже.
- Для JVM класс Optional не оказывает положительного эффекта, однако может оказать отрицательный.
- Если вам надежность важнее скорости (например, нагрузка не такая большая, а данные серьезные), то Optional может помочь сделать код лучше.

И еще раз - это холивар, четкого и однозначного ответа нет.